# start datetime and end datetime are not recorded in database when an event is dragged-and-dropped in the day view of FullCalendar

Tags: events, datetime, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar, drag

I am trying to update the start datetime and the end datetime in the database whenever I drag-and-drop an event in day view in FullCalendar. This is a part of my code:

```
eventDrop: function(event){
    var id = event.id;
    var start = event.start;
    var end = event.end;
    var table = [id, start, end];
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{asset('bundles/ikprojhome/phptest/moslem16.php')}}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {table: table}, 
    });
}
```

By the way, this is the code of the file moslem16.php :

```
    <?php
$myArray = $_REQUEST['table'];
$a = $myArray[0];
$b = $myArray[1];
$c = $myArray[2];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","wkayetdb");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE eventsgroupe SET start='".$b."', end='".$c."' WHERE id='".$a."'");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And this is the structure of the table "eventsgroupe" in the database (the name of the field is on the left and its type is on the right):

id :               int(15)
title :            varchar(255)
start :           datetime
end :             datetime
location :        varchar(255)
description :     varchar(255)
admingroupe_id :  int(20)
idgroupe :        int(20)
partger :         tinyint(1)

The problem is that after a drag-and-drop of an event in the day view, the value of each of the filed "start" and the field "end" in the table "eventsgroupe" becomes the following one: 0000-00-00 00:00:00 .
So my questions are:

1. What is the wrong in my code?
2. How to record the correct start datetime and end datetime of the event after dragging-and-dropping it in the day view in FullCalendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!!. I changed the first code as below:

```
eventDrop: function(event){
   var id = event.id;
   var start = event.start;
   var end = event.end;
   var startdate = [[start.getFullYear(), AddZero(start.getMonth() + 1), AddZero(start.getDate())].join("-"), [AddZero(start.getHours()), AddZero(start.getMinutes())].join(":"), start.getHours() >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM"].join(" ");
   var enddate = [[end.getFullYear(), AddZero(end.getMonth() + 1), AddZero(end.getDate())].join("-"), [AddZero(end.getHours()), AddZero(end.getMinutes())].join(":"), end.getHours() >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM"].join(" ");
   function AddZero(num) {
        return (num >= 0 && num < 10) ? "0" + num : num + "";
    }
    var startdate1 = startdate.substring(0, startdate.length - 3) + ":00";
    var enddate1 = enddate.substring(0, enddate.length - 3) + ":00";
    var table = [id, startdate1, enddate1];
    $.ajax({
      url: '{{asset('bundles/ikprojhome/phptest/moslem16.php')}}',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {table: table},
    });
}
```

And I changed the second code as below:

```
    <?php
$myArray = $_REQUEST['table'];
$a = $myArray[0];
$b = $myArray[1];
$c = $myArray[2];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","wkayetdb");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE eventsgroupe SET start='".$b."', end='".$c."' WHERE id='".$a."'");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Now it works correctly!!